# match string with only symbols in it

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to check if a string contains ONLY special characters in it. If it only has `!@#$%^&*()_+`in it, I want it to do exit. If it's got one letter in it, `!@#$%^&*()_+d.` I want to remove everything except the letter `d` and `.`

Here's the condition so far for the whole string as being comprised of just symbols that doesn't seem to work.

```
if (everything.matches("[-/@#$%^&_+=().]")){
    System.err.println("This only contained symbols, exit");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Why isn't this working? `everything` is a string too!

Also, how would I get to check if there's a `letter` and a `.` as well in the string and when it is, remove all the symbols except the `letter` and the `.`

Thank you.

Test file for one letter and a `.` : http://iforce.co.nz/i/ywvy2ev4.tbb.png
Test for for all special characters : http://iforce.co.nz/i/pw3c2iuf.ccq.png

my `everything` variable when I want to match only letters AND `.` : `^&*^&*(^&*(d&*&.*`

my `everything` variable when I want to match just characters: `%^&^%.##`

This is my complete code up until I use the regex to check:

```
//load the file into a bufferedreader
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]))) {

    //read the first line and then while there's a line, append it to sb
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    //turn sb into string
    everything = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
//if everything.contains only symbols.
//exit
everything = checkStringLegitimacy(everything);

public static String checkStringLegitimacy(String str){
String newString = "";
System.out.println(str);
if (str.matches("[-/@#$%^&_+=()*.]*")){
    System.err.println("This only contained symbols, exit");
    System.exit(0);
}else if(str.matches("[-/@#$%^&_+=()*d.]*")){
//lets remove every character which is not `d` or `.`
    newString = str.replaceAll("[^d.]","");
    System.out.println("str"+str);
    return newString;
}
System.out.println("checkedstringlegit");
return str;
```

}

Comment: Could you post examples of input and expected results?

Comment: Updated original post with input and output

Comment: Does this images show only part of `everything` or is it entire string? Also why posting links to images instead of posting text? This makes helping you harder because we need to rewrite your examples instead of copying them.

Comment: Updated my original post

Comment: What is printed by `System.out.println(str);` inside `checkStringLegitimacy(String str)` method? Is it one line or many lines?

Comment: Only looks like one line.

Comment: In that case it looks like your code is working properly to me: http://ideone.com/VExQhF unless I don't understand what results you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following idiom to match only non-alphanumerics (I also added non-whitespaces here):

```
String[] test = {"!@#$%^&*()_+d.", "@#$%^&*()_+"};
// iterating test cases
for (String s: test) {
    //                 | replacing
    //                 |            | non-alnums/whitespaces
    //                 |            | (character class)
    //                 |            |                 | with empty string
    //                 |            |                 | 
    String replaced = s.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alnum}\\s]", "");
    System.out.printf(
        "Replaced: %s%nNeed to quit? %b%n", 
        replaced, 
        replaced.isEmpty()
    );
}
```

**Output**

```
Replaced: d
Need to quit? false
Replaced: 
Need to quit? true
```

Answer (score 0):

Pasting your expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/zP0aZ5/1), it complained about an unescaped delimeter. Thus, you would need to escape your `/` and make it `\/`.

To check if a string has an (English) character and a period in it, you could use `([a-zA-z].+?\.)|(\..+?[a-zA-z])` or more simply, try to match `[A-Za-z]` and ensure that `indexOf(".")` does not yield -1. To remove anything which is not a period or an English character, simply use `.replace("[^A-Za-z.]", "")`. This will remove anything which is not a letter or a period and replace it with an empty string.

Comment: I escaped that character and it's still complaining about the `illegal escape character`

Comment: my test files: with a letter and a `.` -- http://iforce.co.nz/i/ywvy2ev4.tbb.png
with just special chars:  http://iforce.co.nz/i/pw3c2iuf.ccq.png

Comment: @magna_nz: Please provide some sample values of your `everything` variable. I've tried your code and as is, your code does not throw any exceptions or errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern only match 1 times, you should add * like this

```
if (everything.matches("^[!@#$%^&*()_+]*$")){
    System.err.println("This only contained symbols, exit");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`matches` checks if entire string can be matched by regex, but in

```
everything.matches("[-/@#$%^&_+=().]")
```

regex can match only one character, so you can add

- `*` quantifier to let it match zero or more characters of that type,
- or `+` quantifier, to let it match one or more characters of that type

So assuming that you also don't want to pass empty strings you can use

```
everything.matches("[-/@#$%^&_+=().]*")
```

Now about `d` and `.` part.. You can simply add another condition after already mentioned one to check if this time it contains also `d` or `.` and them remove everything except these characters like

```
if (everything.matches("[-/@#$%^&_+=().]*")){
    System.err.println("This only contained symbols, exit");
    System.exit(0);
}else if(everything.matches("[-/@#$%^&_+=()d.]*")){
    //lets remove every character which is not `d` or `.`
    everything = everything.replaceAll("[^d.]","");
}
```

EDIT:

You missed `*` character in your regex. Try with

```
if (everything.matches("[-/@#$%^&_+=()*.]")){
    System.err.println("This only contained symbols, exit");
    System.exit(0);
}else if(everything.matches("[-/@#$%^&_+=()*d.]*")){
    //lets remove every character which is not `d` or `.`
    everything = everything.replaceAll("[^d.]","");
    System.out.println(everything);
}
```

Or if you want to accept any letter replace `d` with `a-zA-Z`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but for some reason it's still not picking it up. None of these print line statements are being executed. http://iforce.co.nz/i/ytqkijfi.n0x.png

Comment: @magna_nz It suggests that `everything` doesn't match any of `[-/@#$%^&_+=().]` or `[-/@#$%^&_+=()d.]*` expressions fully. So to help you I would need to know what `everything` is exactly.

Comment: @magna_nz Posting examples of input and expected output would be very helpful (as already mentioned by my comment under your question).

Comment: Please see my test file input in the below comment

Comment: It's still not working. None of those regex statements are capturing the input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80376/discussion-between-magna-nz-and-pshemo).

Comment: Works fine for me: http://ideone.com/YRWfRe Maybe problem is how you are capturing the input.

Comment: @magna_nz Oh, and I would rather avoid chat since I am not on Stack Overflow all the time. I visit this question in my spare time, so please try to provide in your question as much details about problem as you can so I (and any other answerers) could read them without having to ask you about every single detail.

Comment: Thanks @Pshemo, I have updated the original post with my code for everything up until the regex point. Thanks